# How to get all data on page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

How to get all data on web-page more correctly using Django?

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Student


def get_students(request):
  students = Student.objects.all()
  return HttpResponse(''.join(f'<p>{student}</p>' for student in students))
```

Comment: Use render function with template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This way you can query all the data from the model and show it on the web page.**

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Student  


def get_students(request):
students = Student.objects.all()
context =  {'students ': students,}
return render (request, '/index.html', context)
```

index.html

**Now you can take all the data from the model with {{student.name}}.**

```
 {% for student in students %}
   
  {{student.name}}

  {% endfor %}
```